# Beta community blogs use old Sketchy favicon

Tags: bug, design, blog-overflow, favicon

The favicons on beta community blog sites use the old Sketchy version rather than the new Grainy versions:

[image: Sketchy Fitness and Nutrition Favicon]

[image: Sketchy Christianity Favicon]